# React-Native import files outside of main directory

Tags: javascript, import, react-native, node-modules

I am trying to make a demo app for some components using `Expo` and `react-native`. (Or I also could use regular `React-Native`)

My problem is I cannot import files outside of the demo app

Here is the structure I have

`|-- Components/
|  |-- libs
|  |-- node_modules
|  |-- index.js
|  |-- package.json
|  |-- demo/
|  |  |-- node_modules
|  |  |-- App.js
|  |  |-- package.json`

Inside of `demo/App.js`, I am trying to import one of my components from the upper directory but with no luck. All the components are exported in ./index.js

Inside of `App.js`, I tried :
`import {MyComponent} from 'Components'`, `import {MyComponent} from '../index'`, or `import {MyComponent} from '../../Components/'` but none seem to work.

I got the following type of error `Directory /Users/kevin/web/myprojects/Components/index doesn't exist`

What Am I doing wrong ?

Comment: try explicitly resolving paths in your App.js. Add this line and check again: app.use('/Components', express.static(__dirname + '/Components/'));

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using `express`, I am using [https://expo.io/]

Answer (score 4):

The way the react-native packager works right now, it's just going to scan the roots of your project and below when creating the JavaScript bundle, so it will be really hard to do this.

You basically just need to put the files under the root of your directory. There are some tools out there for syncing files from another directory into a directory under the root so you could use one of those if you really need to.

Some people are working on ways to make symlinks work with this. Notably, you might look at Haul from Callstack. https://github.com/callstack-io/haul 
But that isn't integrated into Expo yet.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was afraid I would run into these sorts of things. I ll see what I can do.

Comment: This really sucks in the case that you have a web app and a native app that share some common code. You're forced to depend on the same version of react, which can get into an impossible bind when arises versioning issues with other dependencies. I just got bitten by this.

Comment: Any solution to this? I am bit by this too

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy: the author of [this blog post](https://medium.com/the-many/code-sharing-between-react-native-and-react-web-apps-b1e1de22fc53) provides a possible solution. Search for "symlink" in that page to find it. It basically involves triggering babel transformations on top-level .js files that have changed, before copying them into a directory accessible to the react-native app.

Comment: Another idea to find a solution : read through the (very long) issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/637. It offers a lot of suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into the Metro configurations, the `watchFolder` is configured there. And according to its specification is what you want!

> watchFolders
>
> Type: Array
>
> Specify any additional (to projectRoot) watch folders, this is used to know which files to watch.

Check the link bellow:

https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration#watchfolders

## Be careful !

As I noted in your question, you have 2 `node_modules` folders

> Having more than one `node_modules` can break the metro's compilation.

To resolve this situation take a look in the `resolver.extraNodeModules` configuration in metro config.

https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration/#extranodemodules

Comment: does link are not working anymore

Comment: links were updated, thanks Anthony

Answer (score 3):

You could turn the root folder into a local npm package...

1. In the root folder, open `package.json`
2. Set the `name` field in `package.json`
3. Run `npm pack`.
4. Copy the gz tarball name given at the end of the terminal.
5. Open the directory of your `App.js`
6. Run `npm install ../NAME_OF_TARBALL_THAT_YOU_COPIED`
7. In the file, do `import {MyComponent} from 'NAME_IN_PACKAGE.JSON'`

Answer (score 2):

You can try update **metro.config.js** (RN 0.69.3)

```
 const path = require('path');

 module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
     transform: {
      experimentalImportSupport: false,
      inlineRequires: true,
    },
  }),
 },
 // options for reading data outside root react-native folder
 projectRoot: __dirname,
 watchFolders: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../')],
};
```

Merto config docs https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration#watchfolders

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **rn-cli.config.js** file in demo folder and add the following code:

```
var path = require("path");
var config = {
    watchFolders: [
     path.resolve(__dirname,"../"),
    ]
}
module.exports = config;
```

Ref: [View options in here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/understanding-cli#cli-configs)

After running `react-native run-android` or `react-native start`, if you see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHFC6.png), it worked.

Comment: Doesn't work for react native 0.60+. Check Renan's answer instead.